# Logging Hibernate in spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, spring-boot

Please tell me. I have a project on Spring-boot. I'm trying to configure logging in the java code. The problem is that I understand how to configure synchronous logging application and Hibernate SQL.
Here my configuration class for logging app and its works fine:

```
@Service
public class Slf4j {

    @Bean(name = "logger")
    public Logger getLogger() {
        LoggerContext logCtx = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        Logger log = logCtx.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        log.setAdditive(false);
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        log.addAppender(initConsoleLogger(logCtx));
        log.addAppender(initFileLogger(logCtx));
        return log;
    }

    private RollingFileAppender initFileLogger(LoggerContext logCtx) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder logEncoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        logEncoder.setContext(logCtx);
        logEncoder.setPattern("%-12date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n");
        logEncoder.start();

        RollingFileAppender logFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender();
        logFileAppender.setContext(logCtx);
        logFileAppender.setName("logFile");
        logFileAppender.setEncoder(logEncoder);
        logFileAppender.setAppend(true);
        logFileAppender.setFile("logs/logfile.log");

        TimeBasedRollingPolicy logFilePolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy();
        logFilePolicy.setContext(logCtx);
        logFilePolicy.setParent(logFileAppender);
        logFilePolicy.setFileNamePattern("logs/logfile-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log");
        logFilePolicy.setMaxHistory(7);
        logFilePolicy.start();

        logFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(logFilePolicy);
        logFileAppender.start();
        return logFileAppender;
    }

    private ConsoleAppender initConsoleLogger(LoggerContext logCtx) {
        PatternLayoutEncoder logEncoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
        logEncoder.setContext(logCtx);
        logEncoder.setPattern("%-12date{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level - %msg%n");
        logEncoder.start();

        ConsoleAppender logConsoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
        logConsoleAppender.setContext(logCtx);
        logConsoleAppender.setName("console");
        logConsoleAppender.setEncoder(logEncoder);
        logConsoleAppender.start();
        return logConsoleAppender;
    }


}
```

I tried to make a separate class specifically for Hibernate. And write to another file. The file is created but no information. I try user some thing like this in another class Logger log = logCtx.getLogger("org.hibernate.SQL");

UPDATE:

In the end what I want: I want to configure the logging of my application in java code. That is, the log should be written to the logs of the application and SQL queries. And

Comment: There is an app properties key for it that you can enable so that hibernate logs the SQL queries it generates. It had "show SQL" in it, but I don't remember exactly off the top of my head.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce in that case, I need to configure Hibernate without application.properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much easier than I expected. Needed for Hibernate logger to specify the logging level and to create a logger to use the "org.hibernate"